# Solving Linear Equations, with 3 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, fractions

$$6x-8y=24$$

$$\frac{-2}{3}x+ \frac{8}{9}y = m$$

I want to solve for all three of the variables. I did plot this into my calculator and the answer is $$\frac{-8}{3}$$ I want to know the process in solving it.

Comment: Two linear equations will not determine $3$ unknowns uniquely. Furthermore, how is "$-\frac{8}{3}$" an answer when asking for the values of $3$ unknowns?

Comment: Do u know Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @christoph well asked lol

Answer (score 1):

Since you has three unknowns, you need three equations to be able to solve for all three variables (your system of linear equations is *underdetermined*).

However, what you can do is solve for $m$.

Multiplying the second equation through by $-9$ we get:

$$ 6x - 8y = -9m$$

Aha! This looks a lot like our first equation: we already know $6x - 8y = 24$. Putting these together gives $-9m = 24$ and hence $$m = -\frac{8}{3}$$

However, without another equation we cannot determine $x$ and $y$ (for example, both $x = 0, y=-3$ and $x = 4, y=0$ satisfy your system of equations. In fact, there will be infinitely many values of $x$ and $y$ satisfying the two equations).

Answer (score 1):

From $\frac{-2}{3}x+ \frac{8}{9}y = m$ we get $-6x+8y=9m$. If we add this to the first equation we get $24+9m=0$, hence $m=\frac{-8}{3}.$

It remains only one equation: $ 6x-8y=24$. There are infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ which are solutions of this equation.